# Problems with pointers?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have been scratching my head for hours trying to figure out why this is crashing.

This is what it basically does.

I have a gui component called Table. I need 1000 tables. No more, no less. Table inherits from Widget and DynamicElement at the same time. I need to be able to pass around the address of the component (the pointer, not a copy) so I need them not to move.

The first attempt I did worked. I used a vector of Table* and each of the tables were separately allocated on the heap. This method is a bit slow and risks fragmenting the heap for nothing because I need exactly 1000.

The next solution I came up with is for the parent class to have Table m_tables[1000].

I see no reason why this should not work, but when I do it like this, it crashes. In fact, any time I seem to try to do something involving &m_tables[x] something goes wrong.

It crashes with 0xccccccccc violation whenever something tries to access the pointer obtained by doing &m_tables[i].

Is there something I am not understanding?

Here is how I create a table:

```
void LobbyTableManager::createTable( int tableId )
    {
        m_tables[tableId] = LobbyTable(m_fontMan,m_spriteMan,tableId);
        LobbyTable* t = &m_tables[tableId];
        t->addChairActionListeners(this);
        t->addMouseListener(this);
        t->addChairMouseListeners(this);
        t->getTable()->addMouseListener(this);
        t->rescale(1.0f);
        m_activeTables.push_back(t);
        //rescaleTables();

        m_flow->add(t);
        resizeFlow();
        updateScrollBars();
    }
```

I add the table to the flow layout and the second it tries to use it it crashes.

I tried using a std list which should theoretically produce the same result as my first attempt but that crashes too.

Thanks

Comment: Use a debugger to solve the crashes.

Comment: The debugger does not give me much at all, it just gives me access violations.

Comment: Are you calling a constructor at this line `LobbyTable(m_fontMan,m_spriteMan,tableId);`? If you have a tableId doesn't that mean that the table was already created?

Comment: It was created using the default, useless constructor.

Comment: Shouldn't calls to a constructor involve the `new` keyword?

Comment: @Milo The debugger should give you the exact location of the crash, as well as letting you examine the variables involved. Also, problems with pointers often manifests as access violations.

Comment: Is m_tables already allocated to the correct size? Is tableid in the valid range?

Comment: Posting the definition of `LobbyTable` might help. Are you sure there's no problem with its destructor or copy constructor (if it needs one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC Debug builds initialize uninitialized variables with 0xCCCCCCCC.

([list of special values](http://www.docsultant.com/site2/articles/debug_codes.html))

Start the program under the debugger so you can see on which line of code that happens. If it's not your code, go up the call stack until you are inside "your" code.

Comment: It crashes when it tries to render the table which does not make much sense, feels like heap corruption or something. If I remove render calls it just crashes somewhere else.

Comment: Check how the variable that is accessed gets initialized.(Rule out all other things before assuming heap corruption, as it can cause all kinds of symptoms).

Comment: Then why would it not work with std list where  I would push back?

Comment: I can't tell from the code given -  
Whip out the debugger, at the point of the access violation, inspect local variables for incorrect values, see where their values should get initialized, step through again with the debugger to see if they do get initialized correctly, or where they "lose" their values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what else your program does, or how large your table structure is, but could it be that you've filled your stack and are getting an overflow? That'd explain why you get the error when allocating everything on the stack, and not when you're putting it on the heap.

I've had similar problems when going from heap to stack before...